# How to make this arrays combination algorithm more efficient?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, dynamic, pseudocode

So far I have a for loop that goes through a, then another for loop that checks with values of b, and then takes the highest values of c and places that into the new array

```
D = [0, 0, 0]
for i in A
    highestToAdd = 0
    for j in B
        if B[j] < A[i]
            if C[j] > highestToAdd 
                highestToAdd = C[j]
    D[i] = highestToAdd
return D
```

```
input arrays:
A = [3, 1, 7]
B = [5, 0, 2] 
C = [5, 3, 25]

output array is:
D = [25, 3, 25]
```

Here you can see we got 25 twice, and we had to loop through the entirety of b more than once, to find the highest value in c to find it.

As you can see I would be looping for every value of a with every value of b again and again (especially when the 3 array sizes increase), what direction should I take?

**Edit - larger sample**

```
A = [5, 2, 1, 9, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2]
B = [8, 1, 7, 10, 6, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3]
C = [9, 5, 8, 4, 6, 10, 3, 9, 6, 8]

would result in
D = [10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of this logic, but it at least works for the sample test(s).

I stored `B` and `C` elements as suggested by @Dave as pairs and sorted the list in descending order of `C` values.

Now, I did something like: for each element `(ci, bi)`, find all elements in `A` such that `aj > bi`. Mark `j`th position as visited (to prevent re-assigning other `ci` later) and store `ci` at `j`th index in output array.

```
A = [3, 1, 7]
B = [5, 0, 2]
C = [5, 3, 25]
E = []
for i in range(len(C)):
    E.append((C[i], B[i]))

E.sort(reverse = True)

D = {}
visited = [False] * len(B)
for c, b in E:
    ind = 0
    for a in A:
        if not visited[ind] and a >= b:
            D[ind] = c
            visited[ind] = True
        ind += 1

print(D)
```

Comment: Not sure about the visited as it is incorrect for the values A = [5, 2, 1, 9, 3, 1, 5, 4, 2, 2], B = [8, 1, 7, 10, 6, 2, 5, 2, 4, 3] and C = [9, 5, 8, 4, 6, 10, 3, 9, 6, 8], D should be = [10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10]

Comment: @Casabias, there was a slight mistake, instead of `a > b`, it should be `a >= b`. It works then for the given larger input. Made the edits, check it out!

Comment: Thanks! If the array sizes are maxed to 10 elements and each element are between 1 to 10, isn't sorting the array going to take more time than the 2 loops above?

Comment: That's possible, in that case, using insertion sort can help. I had read somewhere that for smaller no. of elements, insertion sort works faster. You can design a method `custom_sort()` which checks if the no. of elements is less than, say 10, then do insertion sort, else use `sort()` method.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/lectures/23Quicksort.pdf) where I read it (Pg. 27).

Comment: this is great, however after comparing, sorting takes too many nanoseconds when comparing with a brute force of 2 loops, and brute force is also quite slow, if I'm trying to find the sum of D instead, would the entire thing need to be changed? So far I just added c to the sum rather than saving it into D.

Comment: Brute force of 2 loops will be slower than sorting for large input sizes (that's what I think). I don't know if sorting can be avoided, but in this situation, it is helping a bit so get to a solution (even if there is a cost to sorting). If you are trying to find the sum, then there are two possibilities: one, that this approach is the only way, second, there is some way better approach to get the sum. About second one, I can't think of any yet, but if I found a better one, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could associate every element of B with its matching element in C, then sort the combined A & B by value.

I.e.,

```
A = [3, 1, 7]
B = [5, 0, 2]
C = [5, 3, 25]
sorted = [(0,B,3), (1,A), (2,B,25), (3,A), (5,B,5), (7,A) ]
```

Then in processing this, you take the max of the matching elements in C and associate them with elements of A when you reach them.

```
(0,B,3): max = 3
(1,A): A.1 is associated with 3
(2,B,25): max = 25
(3,A): A.3 is associated with 25
(5,B,5): max = 25
(7,A): A.7 is associated with 25.
```

Final answer: [25,3,25]

Running time: O(n log n)

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean by associating every element of B with its matching element in C?

Comment: @Casabias It means to keep them as pairs (0,3), (2,25), (5,5) in which the first element is from B and the second is the corresponding element from C. In which answer he put a B in the pair, to decorate it and distinguish them from the elements of A, which he decorated with an A.

Comment: Okay still a bit lost, you want to create another array of key values so [(0,3), (2,25),  (5,5)] then merge with the values of A and then sort it?

Comment: @Casabias Sort them by the first component. In this way the elements of B are sorted, the elements of A are also sorted and in between with the elements of B less than them preceding.

Comment: Okay so I have the final sorted array of  [(0,3), (1), (2, 25), (3), (5,5), (7)], but then when you take the max of the matching elements is it between (0,3)(1) = 3 and between (2,25)(3) = 25, but then how do you get 25 for (5,5)(7)?

Comment: @Casabias You keep the maximum as you travel the list from left to right. When you get to one of the elements of A you output the current maximum. So, you read (0,3). The current maximum is 3. Then you read (1), which is an element of A. You output the current maximum, 3. Then you read (2,25). The current maximum becomes 25. When reading (3), since it is an element from A, you output the current maximum, 25. When you read the next entry (5,5) the current maximum doesn't change. Then you read (7). Since it is an element from A, you output the current maximum, still 25.

Comment: @Casabias By the way, you may note that the values were output as 3, 25, 25 and not as 25,3,25. But note that at the moment of outputting them you know which element of A is associated to each output. You will need to keep the elements of A in a structure that lets you find for each element of A, its position in the original array. This can be done with a hash table that maps elements of A to its position(s) in the original A.